# Session State SQLServer deleting static variables in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Today I had to "upgrade" my project from the Default inProc to a SQLServer session state. As i completed the transition one of the methods in my code stopped working properly. Its a method that calls a static List var, first for count, then for values and it calls it on every page (part of the Master page). Up until now it was working perfectly fine, outputting values and persisting, but now, quite shortly after logging in and setting the session state vars, the static variables would be erased and i get Null Pointer Exception.

Since they were in their own class I managed to find a solution, by moving them to the page they were called, but what might be causing this problem in the first place.

To conclude, static List string variables get erased and nulled shortly after they are created (opposed to working perfectly fine before) and this is connected to me implementing SQLServer as a session Staste (opposed to using inproc before).

Thanks.

EDIT:

What GetTabs (where the static varibles were) was:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

public class GetTabs
{


    public static List<string> listLbl;
    public static List<string> listHead;
    public static string log_idd;
    public static string accesss;
    int i = 0;

    DbConn dbc = new DbConn();


    public void ReturnTabs(int log_id, int access)
    {
        dbc.StoredProcedureTOReturnTabsNames(log_id, access, out listLbl, out listHead);

    }
    public void ReturnTabsMobile(int log_id, int access)
    {
        dbc.StoredProcedureTOReturnTabsNamesForMobiles(log_id, access, out listLbl, out listHead);

    }


}
```

And that was called in another class with GetTabs.listLbl[x] ...
Now i moved the variables and the methods to that class and simply removed the "GetTabs." from my other methods.

Even if the class is in some way incorrect, it was working perfectly fine before i changed the session variable mode.

EDIT2: The DataBase of which, these two methods draw data is different than the one I use for Session State.

EDIT3: After I moved my static variables to the calling class they look like this:

```
public class Functions : System.Web.UI.Page
{ ...
  public void method1(Panel pnn)
{
    ReturnTabs(CheckUser.user_id, CheckUser.user_access);
    int i = listLbl.Count;
    for (int n = 0; n < i; n++)
    {
        LinkButton l = new LinkButton();
        Label lbl = new Label();
        l.ID = "lb" + n;

        l.CommandArgument = n.ToString();
        l.Command += Do_Something;



        lbl.Text = listLbl[n];// +"  " + GetTabs.log_idd + "   " + GetTabs.accesss; //GetTabs.listHead[n];
        Panel pnl = new Panel();
```

And so on , buttons that work as programatically generated header menu are created and placed.

And that is called onLoad in my Master with a Panel from the Master.

Comment: Change your variable to a property and add a breakpoint in the setter with a condition on value == null. Also, is your static variable marked as thread static ?

Comment: Quite a mystery. There is no connection between static class members and Session or Session state mode. We don't know what your code does that makes static variable[s] become null when Session is switched to SQL Server.

Comment: would it be too much to as you to post the code, can you post what it was originally vs what you have changed the code to..

Comment: @Igor I know, and nowhere in my code i even come close to nulling the variables.

MethodMan Please find above.

Comment: what code calls `ReturnTabs`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was very wrong. A static class member is shared by all threads in the process. You called `dbc.StoredProcedureTOReturnTabsNames` multiple times for different users possibly at the same time (in parallel threads), [re]assigning `listLbl` and `listHead` multiple times.

Do the contents of `listLbl` and `listHead` depend on `CheckUser.user_id` and  `CheckUser.user_access`? Are these two another pair of static's?

Comment: Pretty much on every page - OnLoad, and for every User. That explains a lot then. I'll certainly strafe away from using this approach.

Comment: Yes they heavily do rely on them (different access levels have different tabs to display). And yes again, they are statics, but they are yet to cause problems in any way.